# Formal quibbles with my proof of Bolzano-Weierstrass for $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> **Multidimensional Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem.** If $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded sequence, then $(X_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence.

Let $X_n = ((X_n)_1, \dots, (X_n)_n)$ be the sequence vector. Since the sequence vector is bounded iff every coordinate is bounded, we know $(X_n)_1$ is bounded. Applying one-dimensional B-W, we get a strictly increasing $k_1: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $(X_{n_{k_1}})_1$ is a convergent subsequence ($k_1$ being the indexing function).

Then we move on to the subsequence $(X_{n_{k_1}})_2$ which is also bounded. B-W implies there's another $k_2: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $(X_{n_{{k_1}_{k_2}}})_2$ is a convergent subsequence.

Repeating this process until the last coordinate, we get

$$(X_{n_{k^*}})_n$$

where $k^* = k_n \circ k_{n-1} \circ \dots \circ k_1$ is a composition of strictly increasing functions (itself strictly increasing). Then

$$X'_n = ((X_{n_{k^*}})_1, \dots, (X_{n_{k^*}})_n)$$

is a convergent subsequence of the original sequence because: (i) the last coordinate is convergent by construction, (ii) the others are subsequences of convergent subsequences, therefore, they themselves converge.

**Is this appeal to indexing functions correct?**